Ways to select items on a circle such that no two selected items have exactly $n$ items between them.
Let $S_1$ be the number of ways to choose from a circle of 2025 dogs such that no two selected dogs have exactly two dogs (whether selected or not) in between them.
Let $S_2$ be the number of ways to choose from a circle of 2025 cats such that no two selected cats have exactly five cats (whether selected or not) in between them.
How to prove that (i) $S_1 = S_2$ and (ii) both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are perfect cubes?
For (i) I think it's sufficient to prove the number of ways to choose from a circle of 2025 dogs such that at least a pair of selected dogs have exactly two dogs in between them = the number of ways to choose from a circle of 2025 cats such that at least a pair of selected cats have exactly five cats in between them? But I am completely lost on how to prove (ii).

Let $S_1$ be the number of ways to choose <How many?> from a circle of 2025 dogs such that...

Any number as long as no two selected dogs/cats have exactly 2/5 dogs/cats between them

Hints: Number the dogs from $0, 1, \ldots, 2024$ going around the circle. Select your subset of dogs. Then, rearrange the dogs into three circles:
(1) Dogs $0, 3, 6, 9, \ldots, 2022$ (Dog $2022$ is next to Dog $0$)
(2) Dogs $1, 4, 7, 10, \ldots, 2023$ (Dog $2023$ is next to Dog $1$)
(3) Dogs $2, 5, 8, 11, \ldots, 2024$ (Dog $2024$ is next to Dog $2$)
No two selected dogs had exactly 2 dogs in between them in the original circle if and only if no two consecutive dogs in each of the three smaller circles were selected. Now suppose $N$ is the number of ways to select some number of dogs in circle (1) such that no two adjacent dogs are selected. How many ways are there to select some number of dogs in circle (2) such that no two adjacent dogs are selected? What about circle (3)? Now what's the total number of ways to select dogs in all three smaller circles such that no two adjacent dogs in a smaller circle are selected?
For the cats, do the same thing, but make the three circles as follows:
(1) Cats $0, 6, 12, 18, \ldots, 2022, 3, 9, 15, \ldots, 2019$
(2) Cats $1, 7, 13, 19, \ldots, 2023, 4, 10, 16, \ldots, 2020$
(3) Cats $2, 8, 14, 20, \ldots, 2024, 5, 11, 17, \ldots, 2021$

So my direction was vaguely correct?

For my first question it's sufficient to prove the number of elements in (1)=(1) for both dogs and cats. Then $S_1=a \cdot b \cdot c$ where $a,b,c$ are ways to choose from 1,2,3 respectively s.t. no two adjacent elements are selected, but because all three circles have the same amount of items, $S_1=a^3$?

@mrbabario Yes, you seem to have the right idea.
